# Can I ask the question regarding job opportunity in programmers?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, career

I am a Thai programmer and would like to find a way to work abroad in order to advance my knowledge and software development career to the next level. Can I ask it here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Career advice is off-topic, as mentioned in the Help Center. It's also one of the off-topic close reasons. Such questions are too unique to your particular situation to be useful to the broader audience of software development professionals.